# undefined variable when passing variable laravel issues

Tags: php, laravel

I have passed a variable from a method in the controller to the view, but it displays the error:

> Undefined variable: advertise (View: C:\Users\SONY\PhpstormProjects\untitled\resources\views\front\second.blade.php)

This is the view:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   @foreach($advertise as $adverr)
       <div class="ohyeah">
           <img src="{{url('image',$adverr->image)}}" width="500%" height="100%">
       </div>
   @endforeach
</div>
```

and this is the route:

```
Route::get('/adver','advertisecontroller@advertise');
```

and this is the controller:

```
public function advertise()
{
    $advertise = advertise::all();
    return view('front.second',compact('advertise'));
}
```

I do not know where the problem is...

Comment: try this way
return view('front.second',['advertise'=>$advertise]);

Comment: you can debug it using dd($advertise) and check is there any value

Answer (score 1):

In Controller i think y use Model `Advertise`:

```
 public function advertise()
 {
      $advertise = Advertise::all();

      return view('front.second',compact('advertise'));
}
```